# Need help logging to site using CURL

Tags: html, curl, screen-scraping

I have some problems logging to a site using CURL.
I think my problem is related to cookie file.

I use cookiejar when I'm logging in to collect the information and then
I use cookiefile to retrieve the information.

The problem is that from some reason the SMIDENTITY is added to the GET request from the browser and my CURL GET request does not contain such thing.

How do I get the SMIDENTITY value?
Do I need to include the  __UT* stuff?

Here is what was going on from the brower side:

```
   GET https://direct.orange.co.il/selfservice/customer/bill4u HTTP/1.1
Host: direct.orange.co.il
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://www.orange.co.il/he-il/support/InnerHelpAssistence_lobby/
Cookie: __utma=242473949.486197456.1287994666.1288193684.1288790469.7; __utmz=242473949.1288176356.3.2.utmcsr=bill4u.orange.co.il|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/action/mainAction; __utmv=242473949.|1=VisitorsStatus=LoggedInClient=1,; SMIDENTITY=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; __utmb=242473949.24.10.1288790469; __utmc=242473949; SMSESSION=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; JSESSIONID=MRvhpHlnRZ9Hps2JcX8kvpQNLRGKRTksCRyTQQkNG82Gkfj8yHGg!574440962
```

And this is from my CURL request:

```
    GET /selfservice/customer/bill4u HTTP/1.1

Host: direct.orange.co.il

Accept: */*

Referer: https://registration.orange.co.il/copa/pages/protected/protectedredirect.aspx?original=http://www.orange.co.il/

Cookie: SMSESSION=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; 
JSESSIONID=MHmJyFmbNZJxLpprzDW4m0d3Z90RYQdZ6rzzLWTtdLy4H1HBf7VP!-1366797818
```

How do I overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What code are you using?

Comment: curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
 curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
 curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_URL, https://direct.orange.co.il/selfservice/customer/bill4u);
 curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, COOKIE_FILE1);
 curl_easy_setopt(_curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT , 20);

Comment: This is weird, sometimes I do manage to get the required page.
But this works like 1 out of 10 attempts.

Comment: Do you have the 1 after FILE like that in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of curl how about use a tool that is meant for this kind of use case, such as [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/).